# What is the meaning of the -F option in grep manual

Tags: regex, linux, grep, command-line-interface

`-F` is an option of `grep`, from the manual below:

> interpret pattern as a list of fixed strings,separated by
>   newlines,any of which is to be matched

My question is

1. How to separated multiple fixed strings, what is the newline character, `\n` or `\`?
2. It seems `grep -F a\nh file` is not valid if I want to find lines which starts with a character `a` or `h`.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `grep`, `-F` will cause patterns to match literally i.e. no Regex interpretation is done on the pattern(s).

Multiple patterns can be inputted by `\n` i.e. newline separation.

Not all shells convert `\n` to newline by default, you can use `$'a\nh'` in that case.

**Example:**

```
$ echo $'foo\nf.o\nba.r\nbaar\n'
foo
f.o
ba.r
baar

$ grep -F $'f.o\nba.r' <<<$'foo\nf.o\nba.r\nbaar\n'
f.o
ba.r
```

Comment: `$'...'` will be interpreted the same way as a C string, but it is a bash extension. While bash doesn't support interpretation of `\n` in strings, dash does. I think the safe call is to use `tmp_var=$(printf "hello\nworld")`

Comment: @heemayl what is `<<<` in shell, it seems that the content after it becomes standard input.

Comment: @Tracy Exactly.. It's called here string (a subtype of heredoc) check `man bash`

Answer (score 0):

By default the pattern is a Basic Regular Expressions (BRE) pattern, but with `-F` it will be interpreted as a literal string with no metacharacters.

You can also use `-E` which will enable Extended Regular Expressions (ERE).

```
% grep -F '..' <<< $'hello\nworld\n...'
...
% grep '..' <<< $'hello\nworld\n...'
hello
world
...
```